# How to add few individual Facebook like buttons iframe version on the same page?

Tags: facebook, button

On my website I need to add few individual Facebook like buttons, the iframe version to like some anchor links separately.

For example, I have few articles wrapped in anchors so could anyone tell me how to add separate Facebook like buttons for each of them.

```
<a name="Article_One">Article content</a>
<a name="Article_Two">Article content</a>
```

I need individual Facebook like buttons.

Answer (score 0):

explain some more details what you exactly want to do.
if you want a like button you can create some code for you with that wizard http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/